# Android - How to get user location with signal strength from cell tower(triangulation or any other way)..?

Tags: android, geolocation

Has anybody tried getting the user location using signal strength from the nearby cell towers(triangulation) or is it even possible to do so in android? I am developing an app with tracking facilities in-case the phone gets stolen. In such a case i need to get the location of the phone without internet/GPS(I would have done that, but since they can't be turned ON programmatically, No luck there). I am NOT looking for a highly accurate location. 
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: take a look at UnifiedNLP project and it's backend LocalGSMBackend .